# Need a fix on my code of recursion (either get needs to return int or stackoverflow error)

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class recursionTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Your recursion is " + Recursion(5,4));
    }    

    private static int Recursion(int recursive1, int recursive2) {

            if(recursive2 == 0)
                return 1; 

            else if (recursive2 >= 0)

            return Recursion(recursive1 * Recursion(recursive1,recursive2-1), recursive2);

    }
}
```

// I am looking more for a fix rather than a suggetion because I already know my problems

Comment: Great you know your problem but I don't know it. So what is a problem you have and what is a question?

Comment: Please note that your code is not compilable since we don't return from method in all cases.

Comment: I keep getting an error on the first line saying it needs to return an int or if I do manage to get it to run it has a stackoverflow error

Comment: what exactly is the function suppose to do, atleast mention that.

Comment: The function is supposed to take two numbers and calculate the recursion based off the formula it the second parameter

Comment: I'm afraid to ask what "calculate the recursion" is...

Comment: If you copy the code into java youll know exactly what Im referring to

Comment: IN this line: `        return Recursion(recursive1 * Recursion(recursive1,recursive2-1), recursive2);` the second parameter never changes.  And so, you will continue to call it until the stack blows up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to calculate the value of x raised to the power of y (i.e. x ^ y) using recursion. The important thing you need to keep in mind is, you need to terminate the function call with some condition; otherwise, it will become endless.

```
public class RecursionTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("5 ^ 4 = " + power(5, 4));
    }

    private static int power(int x, int y) {
        if (y == 0) // Because x ^ 0 = 1
            return 1;
        return x * power(x, y - 1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5 ^ 4 = 625
```

Is this what you were looking for? Feel free to comment if it isn't the case.